# Azure SDK for Kotlin / Android - How can I listen to a queue?

Tags: kotlin

good morning.

I'am on a challenge, I need to listen a queue with a android app that will runs on background, my first problem is: how I can listen a Azure Storage Queue on the app?

This is the repo, https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-android, I saw examples for Retrieve and Peek messages, but I need that the process starts on the moment that a new message is entered on the queue. 
Can someone help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The way you'd normally solve this for a mobile app is to send a push notification to the app. The push notification will wake up the app from the background, and you can then perform some processing - like read the content of the queue. The other way you can do this is with a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), which means it effectively can run in the background and never be shutdown, but it has a permanent notification displayed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK based on your scenario I would recommend you should be moving towards Service Bus Queue. I think it will be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks man, in both services I still having my problem, how to listen this service bus or storage queue ou RabbitMQ queue... on android?